# Developmental testing of programs using Linux's POSIX capabilities

Tags: linux, build, makefile, build-process, linux-capabilities

I'm developing a project where the executables use Linux's [POSIX capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) rather than being setuid root. So far I've had to keep one root shell open so that each time I recompile I can redo the [`setcap`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) command to give the needed capability to the executable file so that I can test the results.  That's getting tedious, plus if I ever hope that anyone else would want to contribute to the project's development I'll have to come up with a better way of doing it.

So far I've come up with two ways of dealing with this:

1) Have a single make target to be run as root to create a special setuid program which will be used to by the makefiles to give the capability to the executables.  The program will be compiled from a template modified via `sed` so that it will only run if used by the non-root user the developer is working as, and will only modify files owned by the developer (and which are sitting in directories owned by the developer which aren't world writeable).

The problem with this is that I'm using [GNU autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) to generate my make files, and I can't figure out how to get the makefiles to run a program on a linked executable after it's been linked.  I could create a `setcap-all` target which has all the executables as its dependencies, with a rule that runs the setuid program on them, but then you can't simply do `make executable-1` if that's all you want to build.

2) Have a single make target to be run as root to create a setuid daemon which will use [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) to monitor the `src` directory and grant the capability to any new executables (and which has security consideration similar to the setuid program from #1).

My problem with this is that I can't figure out how to get the build system to automatically and transparently start up the daemon, plus my intuition that This Is Not The Way Things Are Done in a proper build system.

Are there any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm a bit confused about the question, but it seems you're trying to use the build-system to solve an installation problem.

Whether you're packaging your project using `dpkg`, `rpm` or anything else, there should be a rule to enforce usage of `setcap`, which will set the capabilities of the installed binary using the Filesystem Extended Attributes (xattrs).

```
# Post-install rule example
setcap cap_net_raw=+pe /usr/bin/installed-binary
```

However, of you're installing a system daemon, you may count on the init-script to already have all the capabilities, so it's a matter of letting your process to drop unneeded capabilities.